# Calling String in same class

Tags: java, string, encryption, jbutton, strip

I have this jButton that transfers the text from one text area to another but now I need to make it strip the sentence but I don't know how to call on the strip string. Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
package encryptor;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Encryptor extends javax.swing.JFrame
{  
public Encryptor()
{
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

private void jButtonEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                               
{                                                   
    jTextAreaTarget.setText(jTextAreaSource.getText());
    jButtonEncrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener());
}                                              

public static String strip(String s)
{
    String target = "";
    char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        char c = a[i];
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            target += c;
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: `jTextAreaTarget.setText(strip(jTextAreaSource.getText()))`. I don't want to be rude, but Swing is quite complex, and requires to understand serious OO and threading concepts. If you don't know how to call a method yet, you shouldn't deal with Swing. Practice on basic exercises just printing to System.out. BTW, your event handling code doesn't make sense. This doesn't even compile.

Comment: You should not mix application code and GUI either. Encryption is not something you mix with swing components, if just to avoid complexity (minimize coupling, to be precise).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip everything but alphabets then you can probably use `String.replaceAll()` with `Regex`, see the example below:

```
String s = "dsakufbsa32321ofbs  odsd";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", ""));
```